# Divide an array into k or less subparts to minimize the maximum sum of each part

Tags: arrays, dynamic-programming

I need to divide an array into k or less subparts to minimize the maximum sum of each part.

For example an array has elements: `5,10,21,20`

If `k=2`, the array can be divided in 2 sub-arrays: `{5,10,21}` and `{20}`.
We have to return the maximum sum of the subarray (`36` in above example).

When `k>=4`, the answer will be just the largest element of the array.

Also, the order in which the array elements are chosen cannot be changed, so we can't just sort the array and proceed.

Comment: How are arrays divided? Why not {5, 10} and {21,21}? Which programming language?

Comment: If we divide it like {5,10} and {20,21}, the maximum sum of subarray becomes 41. But this has to be minimized. C, C++ or Java will do. I am just looking for the algo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a greedy solution if you want a good-enough solution:

```
def minmax(lst, k):
    lst = sorted(lst, reverse=True)  # biggest numbers first is usually better
    subs = [[] for _ in xrange(k)]   # create the lists for the subarrays

    while lst:
        subs[0].append(lst.pop(0))         # append to the one with lowest sum
        subs.sort(key=sum)                 # sort by sum (lowest first)
        print subs                   # print the subarrays while creating them

    return sum(subs[-1])    # we have sorted by sums, last has the biggest sum
```

This does not guarantee to produce the best result, but it works pretty well.

### k = 2

This is your example:

```
print 'result is %d' % minmax([5, 10, 21, 20], 2)
```

*Output*

```
[[], [21]]
[[20], [21]]
[[21], [20, 10]]
[[21, 5], [20, 10]]
result is 30
```

Well, it found a better solution than the one you showed.

### k >= 4

Let's try with `k=4` and `k=5`

```
>>> print 'result is %d' % minmax([5, 10, 21, 20], 4)
[[], [], [], [21]]
[[], [], [20], [21]]
[[], [10], [20], [21]]
[[5], [10], [20], [21]]
result is 21

>>> print 'result is %d' % minmax([5, 10, 21, 20], 5)
[[], [], [], [], [21]]
[[], [], [], [20], [21]]
[[], [], [10], [20], [21]]
[[], [5], [10], [20], [21]]
result is 21
```

You could also add this code to the beginning of the function to directly return the max of `lst` when `k >= len(lst)`:

```
def minmax(lst, k):
    if k >= len(lst):
        return max(lst)
    ....
```

### Minimum Makespan Problem

This type of problem is famous with the name of **Minimum Makespan Problem**, searching for it you will retrieve lots of information about algorithms that are guaranteed to produce the optimal result, but their explanation is far too complex for a stack overflow answer, while the greedy one is fun and instructive.

Comment: Well, I did not mention one thing, the order in which the array elements appear cannot change. So, we cannot just sort the array and proceed.
I'm sorry, I didn't mention this before as I thought it was obvious with the example I gave.
I'll append this to the question itself.

Answer (score 6):

Well this is clearly a Dynamic Programming Problem.

The problem of dividing the array is tantamount to put k-1 divisions in the array.

Let you array be called A.
And let m[i,k] be the best division of elements of A till the i-th element with k divisions

```
m[0,*] = 0
m[i,0] = a[i] 
m[i,j] = min{m[i-1,j] + a[i], max{m[i-1,j-1], a[i]}}
```

m[i,j] is the minimum between the dividing the array at point i or not  dividing.

The answer can be found if you calculate

```
m[length(A), k-1]
```

You can backtrack the divisions from there.

Answer (score 1):

A better idea is to use binary search here:

You can test if a candidate value of m(desired maximum sum) is good in O(n), by using a simple greedy algorithm: *just take prefix as long as possible to not exceed m, cut if off, and start again. If this process stops in <=k steps, then you have successfully partitioned the array, so the real answer is either m or something smaller. *.

You can hence binary search on the value of m [0,2^32 - 1].

**Complexity: O(n*log(sum(array)))**

If sum(array) is comparable to n, this algorithm will run in linearithmic time.